# T-SQL Programming . Common Table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would need a help in the following scneario. I am using T-SQL
Following is my table details. Say the table name is #tempk

```
Customer Current_Month Contract Amount
201      2015-09-01     3       100
```

My requirement is to add 12 months from the current month.that is 2016-09-01. Assuming
I am getting the start date of the month. I need the data in the following format

```
Customer Renewal_Month Contract_months  End_Month Amount
201      2015-09-01     3           2016-09-01 100
201      2015-12-01     3           2016-09-01 100
201      2015-03-01     3           2016-09-01 100
201      2015-06-01     3           2016-09-01 100
```

The contract column can have any values
The consquent records are incremental of contract columns from the previous records.
I am using the following query. I have a date dimension table called Dim_Date that has date,quareter,year,month etc..

```
WITH GetProrateCTE (Customer_ID,Renewal_Month,Contract_Months,End_Month,MRR) as
(SELECT Customer_ID,Renewal_Month,Contract_Months,DATEADD(month, 12,Renewal_Month) End_Month,MRR
 from #tempk),
GetRenewalMonths (Customer_ID,Renewal_Month,Contract_Months,End_Month,MRR) as
(
SELECT A.Customer_ID,B.Month Renewal_Month,A.Contract_Months,A.End_Month,A.MRR
FROM GetProrateCTE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Month from DW..Dim_Date B GROUP BY MONTH) B
ON  B.Month between A.Renewal_Month and A.End_Month
)
SELECT G.Customer_ID,G.Renewal_Month,G.Contract_Months,G.End_Month,G.MRR
FROM GetRenewalMonths G
```

Could you please help me to achieve the result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to do this in Common table Expressions. or would it be better if I go cursor.

Comment: what happen if contact months is equal 7. Do you get more than 12 months? or the last period is shorter? Or we round down days? 365/7 = 52.14

Comment: I need to get data for the next 12 months only. For example if the contract months is 7 , I will have the customer only once in next 12 months...

Comment: what is the purpose of contract = 3? does this mean that you need a row every 3 months (4 rows per 12 months) ?

Comment: You are right.  exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in this way -

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT Customer,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,Current_Month), 0) AS Renewal_Month,Contract,DATEADD(YEAR,1,Current_Month) AS End_Month,Amount,1 AS Level FROM #tempk
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Customer,DATEADD(MONTH,t.Contract,c.Renewal_Month),t.Contract,DATEADD(YEAR,1,t.Current_Month) AS End_Month,t.Amount,Level + 1 
FROM #tempk t join CTE c on t.customer = c.customer 
WHERE Level < (12/t.Contract))
SELECT  Customer,Renewal_Month,Contract AS Contract_months,End_Month,Amount 
FROM CTE
```

Just append your logic of the date dimension table to this.

Comment: I am getting error as I cant use aggregation in with recursion when I add INNER JOIN (SELECT Month from DW..Dim_Date B GROUP BY MONTH) B
ON  B.Month between A.Renewal_Month and A.End_Month after FROM #tempk t join CTE c on t.customer = c.customer

Comment: How do I use this in place for LEVEL < 4

Comment: As per Books Online - **The following items are not allowed in the CTE_query_definition of a recursive member: SELECT DISTINCT,
GROUP BY,PIVOT,HAVING,Scalar aggregation,TOP,LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER JOIN (INNER JOIN is allowed),Subqueries etc.**
That's why you got the error.

Comment: Anyways I had used LEVEL < 4 to restrict the query to show only 4 rows (a row every 3 months so 4 rows for 12 months).

Comment: Yeah.. You are right.. Because in my case months can be varying.. can be anything.. i just referred 3 for an example. How can I dynamically limit the records based on this.

Comment: so just replace that part with - `Level < (12/t.Contract)`